# OP Cache configuration in php.ini for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, opcache

A shared Linux web hosting server is running PHP 7.2, and in cPanel > PHP Options, I have enabled OP Cache.

I want to know if there is any way to optimize OP cache for Wordpress using PHP.ini.

I found an article with the following PHP.ini entries:

```
opcache.memory_consumption=256
; The amount of memory for interned strings in Mbytes.
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
; The maximum number of keys (scripts) in the OPcache hash table.
; Only numbers between 200 and 100000 are allowed.
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
; The maximum percentage of “wasted” memory until a restart is scheduled.
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=15
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.force_restart_timeout=300
```

I found adding them all at once increased my webpagetest.org TTFB result.

Disabling them all again reduced my webpagetest.org TTFB result again.

So, is there any way to optimize OP cache for Wordpress using PHP.ini?

Comment: I think there is no such settings specially for Wordpress. WP is just a bunch of PHP pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use W3C Total Cache plugin, the best plugin for caching wordpress.
It supports opcache

The best php.ini settings depend on the hosting/server

I am using these

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```